# How do I stop daghesh from moving when typing in Hebrew

Tags: font, text, internationalization

When typing in Hebrew on macOS 10.13, the daghesh sometimes 'jumps' from one character to another. Here is an example. Initially, the daghesh is in the correct place (שׁ):

[image]

But when I add a 'ה', it jumps into it:

[image]

Bizarrely, with some characters it doesn't jump:

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on here, and how to stop the Daghesh from jumping? It's very annoying!

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

I found that installing the following font fixed this issue – so I presume it is an issue with some of the Hebrew fonts that come installed with macOS?

Here is the font: [SBL HEBREW FONT](https://www.sbl-site.org/educational/BiblicalFonts_SBLHebrew.aspx)